# Is there any API for Oneworld Alliance?

Tags: python

Does anyone know if there is an API for Oneworld Alliance ? The idea is to program in Python a Traveling Salesman, who visits all airports in the system based on actual available flight connections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Oneworld Alliance themselves, or other airlines or alliances, have their own APIs. Not sure whether asking this is ontopic to SO.

Try the search engines and booking sites: Travelocity, Expedia, Hotwire, cheaptickets...
For example by Google here's [Expedia Affiliate Network](http://developer.ean.com/docs/Air).
[Kayak apparently used to have a beta API but it was pulled due to misuse](http://www.kayak.com/labs/api/search/).
Not sure how easy it is to scrape [Oneworld's site or timetables](http://www.oneworld.com/ow/flight-info/where-we-fly), I wouldn't start there.

Remember the airlines have a negative incentive to allow their data to be scraped, whereas the search engines have a positive incentive (within reasonable limits). So start with the latter.

When you say "based on actual available flight connections", I presume you just check whether airline X has a route connecting city A to city B, not at actual seat inventory on specific dates and times, which seems needless. Do you need durations and frequencies?

Btw, there are 900 hits on SO on "Traveling Salesman", you might be able to reuse someone else's data.